# R: how to create an column with values from the first time an event happened

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this, each individual has multiple visits. I want to capture the FDAYS where MCI happened the first time (MCI=1) for each person and put the value into another column called DAYS. Can I do it with dplyr?

```
ID <-  c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
Visit <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3)
MCI <- c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1) 
FDAYS <- c(20,60,40,80,100,30,60,90)
df <- data.frame(ID, Vist, MCI, FDAYS)
```

Tried this but it just gave me the FDAYS of the 1st visit of each person.

```
df %>%
group_by (ID) %>%
mutate(DAYS = case_when(MCI == 1~ min(FDAYS),
                         .default = NA)) %>%
mutate(DAYS = first(na.omit(DAYS)))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! As we can't run code based on data provided as an image, could you please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data shared using `dput()`, i.e. run `dput(head(df, 10))` and copy & paste the output into your post.

Comment: I think something like `df |> mutate(DAYS = min(FDAYS[MCI == 1], na.rm = TRUE), .by = ID)`.  ie, "Take `df`, add variable `DAYS` that is the minimum non-NA `FDAYS` value wherein `MCI` is 1, among each `ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` way using `which.max`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DAYS = FDAYS[which.max(MCI == 1)], .by= ID)
```

```
  ID Visit MCI FDAYS DAYS
1  1     1   0    20   40
2  1     2   1    40   40
3  1     3   0    60   40
4  1     4   1    80   40
5  1     5   0   100   40
6  2     1   0    30   60
7  2     2   1    60   60
8  2     3   1    90   60
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked!! If MCI happened multiple times for a person, it will return the FDAYS of the first time MCI happened?

Comment: Yes it will return the FDAYS  of the first time MCI happened!

Answer (score 0):

If you like to keep all records, we can do

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df |>
  mutate(DAYS = min(FDAYS[MCI == 1L]), .by = ID)
#>   ID Visit MCI FDAYS DAYS
#> 1  1     1   0    20   40
#> 2  1     2   1    40   40
#> 3  1     3   0    60   40
#> 4  1     4   1    80   40
#> 5  1     5   0   100   40
#> 6  2     1   0    30   60
#> 7  2     2   1    60   60
#> 8  2     3   1    90   60
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data**

```r
df = read.table(text = "ID Visit MCI FDAYS DAYS
1 1 0 20 40 
1 2 1 40 40
1 3 0 60 40
1 4 1 80 40
1 5 0 100 40
2 1 0 30 60 
2 2 1 60 60
2 3 1 90 60", header = TRUE)
```